Almost got working 24.04 on vbox 7.0.18
I spent about an hour installing this today, as the installation failed many times. Eventually, instead of skipping that step, I accepted the installer question about using its new version, and it did work!
Well, at least for some time. The machine started, got guest additions, rebooted but after minutes it showed graphic distortions. Then after reboot, the guest additions do not work (the vboxclient logged something but stopped digging). Any known solution? All this vm creation used to be as simple as it should be.

You have tagged 20.04 but ask about 24.04. Some one searching on tags will not see your question.

Please edit your question with the correct Ubuntu version: 20.04 or 24.04. So that the title and the tags are congruent.

Welcome to AskUbuntu. There is an insufficient amount of actionable information here. Could you [edit] your question to include the settings you’ve selected for the virtual machine? Based on what you’ve said, it sounds like the VM does not have the minimum amount of memory, but it’s just a guess based on the lack of detail in the question

Solved
This was the particular host problem. I noticed windows+dell hidden updates pending in the background that revealed themselves at host reboot.
Verified all from scratch, no problems anymore.
The problem appeared after a while - this is apparently due to wayland, disabling it is the latest solution.
https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=110982
